# ASP.Net REST API 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to implement a REST API in ASP.Net MVC. This is my code:

```
[Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class ContactsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("application/xml")]
    [Route("api/areas/{areaName}/contacts/{contactID}")]
    public ActionResult<XmlDocument> Get(string areaName, string contactID)
    {
        return new XmlDocument();
    }
}
```

However, when I surf to `/api/areas/foo/contacts/bar`, I encounter HTTP 404.

How can I fix my code?

Comment: Is foo a valid areaName? Is bar a valid contactID? Do you use any kind of server cache?

Comment: There are two parameters which you need to pass `/api/areas/foo/contacts/bar?areaName=xxx&contactID=yyy`

Comment: @Jayendran foo is the area name and bar is the contact id. No query string.

Comment: Remove the 'api' from one whether in Controller or our method. You put on two places same string api

Comment: @Alon you need to confirm what version of asp.net you are using. `ActionResult<T>` is part of [tag:asp.net-core] and not the previous [tag:asp.net-mvc] version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `ActionResult<T>` is part of [asp.net-core](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) and not the previous [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) version. This means that you originally tagged the question incorrectly.

That said, the URL being called does not match the route template of the intended action and thus you will get a not found when trying to call the action.

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

The provided route has `[Route("api")]` on the controller and `[Route("api/areas/{areaName}/contacts/{contactID}")]` on the action, which when combined would result in a URL that looks like

```
api/api/areas/foo/contacts/bar
```

I believe the intention was to have `api` only once so I would suggest remove one of them

Either from the action

```
[Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class ContactsController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("application/xml")]
    //GET api/areas/foo/contacts/bar
    [Route("areas/{areaName}/contacts/{contactID}")]
    public ActionResult<XmlDocument> Get(string areaName, string contactID) {
        return new XmlDocument();
    }
}
```

or removing the prefix on the controller

```
[ApiController]
public class ContactsController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("application/xml")]
    //GET api/areas/foo/contacts/bar
    [Route("api/areas/{areaName}/contacts/{contactID}")]
    public ActionResult<XmlDocument> Get(string areaName, string contactID) {
        return new XmlDocument();
    }
}
```